# cancel Kotlin coroutine job on certain points

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Kotlin coroutines jobs will be canceled when the execution reaches the first suspendable function. but I want this cancellation to happen on certain points that I want, not any suspendable function calls.

I want to check cancellation on certain points and manually finish the job, just like Thread interruptions.
Assume that a job is running and reached a delay function, then cancellation occurred, I want to catch the cancellation exception and set flag `running = false`, then continue executing the job and finish the job later on where I want.
Consider that I want delay function calls to be cancelled when cancellation occurs, and don't wait for the delay.
Also I want to mention that I'm doing this in android studio.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `invokeOnCompletion` function to do whatever you need when that job is cancelled?

It would be something like this:

```
val job = launch {

    ...

}

job.invokeOnCompletion { 
    if (job.isCancelled) {
        //Do whatever you need here when the job is cancelled
        ...
    }
}
```

If you need to continue with the task after its cancellation, then design it with some kind of checkpoints and then you're set.